# Difference between setAlwaysOnTop in java 1.6 and java 1.7

Tags: java, swing, java-7, java-6

I have a issue with window overlapping in java 1.6 but not in java 1.7.

My current code is like this :

**NOTE : owner is null and textComponent is a JPanel which is added to a different JDialog**

```
 public MyDialog(final Window owner,JComponent textComponent) { 
       super(owner, ModalityType.MODELESS);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.HIDE_ON_CLOSE);
        setAlwaysOnTop(true);
        setLocationRelativeTo(textComponent);
        setLayout(new GridLayout());    
    }

 public void setVisible(final boolean isVisible) {
              super.setVisible(isVisible);
    }
```

Now this Dialog is set on textComponent which has to always stay at the back of this MyDialog.

Now the catch is :

- I have another dialog which is having modality type as APPLICATION_MODAL.
- Now when that dialog comes on top then ideally no window should accept the click but in java 1.6 somehow this textComponent  JPanel accepts the click and sends this MyDialog at back of JDialog holding textComponent JPanel  and never let it come in front.
- But in java 1.7 nothing like this happens. Nor the textComponent JPanel accepts the click and neither MyDialog goes at back of this Dialog holding textComponent .

Now I have a workaround using which this issue in java 1.6 gets resolved but its quite funny to keep in my project without understanding why this is happening.

Solution :

```
 public MyDialog(final Window owner,JComponent textComponent) { 
           super((Frame)null, false);//**new change**
            setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.HIDE_ON_CLOSE);
            setAlwaysOnTop(true);
            setLocationRelativeTo(textComponent);
            setLayout(new GridLayout());    
        }

     public void setVisible(final boolean isVisible) {
                  setAlwaysOnTop(false);//**new change**
                  setAlwaysOnTop(true);//**new change**
                  super.setVisible(isVisible);
        }
```

So I am looking some reasonable explanation regarding

1. why this issue is faced in java 1.6
2. why this solution works, exactly what has been changes in java 1.6 and java 1.7 which is creating this issue and resolving it in a weird way.

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).